# Prevent graph-tool to remap nodes when using load_graph with graphml format

Tags: python, networkx, graph-tool

I am working with some graphs that were previously exported from *networkx* library in *graphml* format.

When I import those files to graph-tool, the following remap the nodes to 0-base index. How can I prevent that? Because I really need to preserve the order.

Example:

```
# Create a graph using networkx with only one edge (10 <-> 20)
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge(10, 20)
nx.write_graphml(g, 'teste.graphml')

# load the previous graph using graph-tool
import graph_tool.all as gt
g = gt.load_graph('teste.graphml')
print(list(g.edges()) # output is an edge from 0 to 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In graph-tool vertices are always indexed from zero, but if the graphml file uses noncanonical indexing, this can be obtained via the `"_graphml_vertex_id"` property map:

```
g = gt.load_graph('teste.graphml')
v = g.vertex(0)
print(g.vp._graphml_vertex_id[v])
```